# Laravel 5 camelCase mutator naming

Tags: php, model, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a coloumn in my database named using camelCase convention how should i put it in the mutator naming to work ?

migration

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('skillTypes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->boolean('needRating');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I named it like that but didnt work and also named it setNeedRatingAttribute and didnt work either

the mutator

```
    public function setneedRatingAttribute($input){
    if($input==null){
        $input=false;
    }
    else{
        $input=true;
    }
    $this->attributes['needRating']=$input;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this property to your Model

```
public static $snakeAttributes = false;
```

and rename method from `setneedRatingAttribute` to `setNeedRatingAttribute`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the mutator you provided works. You could rename it to setNeedRatingAttribute for readability.

Secondly, you can replace the **if** in your setter with:

```
$this->attributes['needRating'] = boolvar($input);
```

Comment: in postgresql  if I dont set it it consider it null so i have to set it to false and i used dd($input) to check if it work but it is never entered

Comment: In case of not null collumns it might happen - but you can just do $this->attributes['needRating'] = boolvar($input); and skip the if. I updated the answer. Anyway, the setter should work

Comment: solved it the reason was it was never sent from the form  so it never entered the mutator  and I thought the problem was in the naming
sorry for the inconvenience thought thanks for your help